# Angular 4 font rendering issue

Tags: angular, fonts

I'm trying to use the padlock glyph (unicode entity &#x1f512;) in Microsoft's Segoe UI Symbol font in an Angular 4 app, but having trouble rendering the glyph depending on where it is in the app. I created this sample HTML:

```
<div style="font-size: 2em">
  <p>Default font: &#x1f512;</p>
  <p style="font-family:'Segoe UI Symbol'">Segoe UI Symbol font: &#x1f512;</p>
</div>
```

If I add this HTML to the app's index.html file the padlock looks fine. But if I add it to the app's app.component.html file, the padlock gets rendered as an empty box. Like so:
[screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yghS.png)

I am running Windows 7 and see the problem in both Firefox and Chrome. My test program was created with Angular-CLI v1.2 and Angular v4.2.6.
Any idea why Angular would behave this way?

Thanks